# Load 50 ImageViews of PNGs error

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, android-imageview

When I try to load 50 light pngs into my android activity I get this error (ligne of the error`setContentView(R.main_activity.xml)`)

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #124: Binary XML file line #124
```

When I remove some of them or all of them, the app runs normally, so I know at least that they are the source of the problem. The images, as I said before, are very light (each 1ko, 50ko in total).Here is an example:

```
        <ImageView                 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            />
        <ImageView                 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            />
....
            <ImageView                 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/img50"
            android:id="@+id/img50"
            />
```

As far as I know 50ko shouldn't be a problem. I was using vectors instead, and they load fine with the help of `AsyncTask` but then the scrollView and everything get very slow. So I decided to use rendered images instead like pngs. But it doesn't seem to be working.  Is there a way to avoid this problem, like loading the images gradually?

PS. for those who wonder why all the images match parent in width and height, it's because they have a transparent background and I want the overlap. (so they are inside a RelativeLayout)

Thanks.

Comment: Images stored in PNG are compressed. So don't look at file size, instead compute memory consuption based on uncompressed picture resolution. And there is canonical example from developer.android: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Thanks. Can I use this method to load png images ? (I thought these are for Bitmaps)

Comment: Why not? I believe the problem is not the format you choose but in the way you loading and manipulating your image data.